# Why is my cronjob not properly calling commands within .sh scripts?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

I'm having an issue with cronjobs in Ubuntu where its calling some commands and not others

cronjob

```
30 * * * * /bin/bash /home/path/script/start.sh >> /tmp/test.txt
```

start.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/path/script

echo "Its working"

/usr/bin/git fetch
/usr/bin/git pull origin

echo "git"

/usr/bin/python3 /home/path/script/main.py &

echo "end"
```

/var/log/syslog

```
CRON[362212]: (ubuntu) CMD (/bin/bash /home/path/script/start.sh >> /tmp/test.txt)
```

test.txt

```
Its working
Updating n83aw46..215iebd
git
end
```

When I `git log` it still shows the previous git commit and when I run `ps -ef | grep .py` nothing shows up.

I have confirmed cron daemon is running. `ps -ef` command also works with my test python script. I've also verified that both the `main.py` and `start.sh` files has `chmod +x`

Comment: Most cron problems are either permissions or environment. Make sure your cron command is running as the user you expect, and make sure it has the environment you expect (e.g. PATH, HOME and whatever else is required).

Comment: Try : `... >> /tmp/test.txt 2> /tmp/test.err`

Comment: And maybe add a `date` command to your script to see when it was executed. Assuming the Python script is rum by the shell script, how long does it run? Do you expect it to be still running when you check this with `ps`?

Comment: What's the point in Running Python in the background? I would remove the `&`, and also have `main.py` printing something to stdout, so that you can see that the program is being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Philippe Your suggestion of adding another err log `... >> /tmp/test.txt 2> /tmp/test.err` helped me resolve the issue.

There was a conflict with local changes and `git pull`. So I had to stash, pull then re-apply the stash.